# property field JCR Multitenancy

Tags: multi-tenant, jackrabbit, jcr

At the Moment I am using Jackrabbit 2.6.3 as JCR backend and i would like to implement a possibility to separate different tenant(e.g. storing a tenant ID).
Is there any standard property that is recommended for this usecase or should i create a custom nodetype that contains the new tenant ID property?
Is multitenancy supported by JCR API or Jackrabbit?
Thanks you advance for helping me.

kind regards,

shan

Answer (score 1):

no multitenancy is not a feature of Jackrabbit. There are different approaches for doing this and it all depends on the requirements. A couple of options that I see would be:

- A workspace for each tenant
- A root folder for each tenant
- A property containing the tenant id. (you can use a mixin for this)